# 'Regular Points' vector layer in Bonn

Tags: qgis, dem, vector, gps, point-cloud

I've downloaded the bonn version of QGIS. Using the 'regular points' vector analysis tool, I've set some 5m regular points over a field so that I can use the x,y coordinates to plot them and measure their z coordinate in the field with a gnss. I am gathering height data for a DTM. When I export the layer in QGIS as a csv file it doesn't give me the coordinate x,y values, only the id.

Answer (score 2):

This is not about "Regular Points" tool. While exporting a layer as CSV, by default, QGIS doesn't save the coordinates. You should choose the coordinates you want to save in `GEOMETRY` field under `Layer options`.

[image]